# Is there a way to make a script that automatically corrects scanned documents?

Tags: linux, shell, imagemagick, gimp

I often scan handwritten documents to send to colleagues, and need to make corrections to the digital file once it's scanned. (For example, I change mistakes I made on the original document to white.)

I am thinking of some script which can do the following:

Take a color scan image (say a tiff) as input, and make simple corrections automatically based on colored corrections in the image.

For example take the simplest case: I write only black on white. There is an area where I made mistakes so I draw a red closed circle (with a pen on the actual sheet of paper) around that area. Then I scan the image (or usually many of them). Now I would like the script to erase each of these areas in all of the images so my mistakes disappear in the resulting image.

Any ideas how to realize this in a Linux environment, e.g. with Image Magick?

---

It looks like Gimp with script-fu could be the way to go it should be powerful enough. Can somebody give me a hint by pointing out the above example would look like in script-fu?

Comment: Also helpfull for me: which linux pixel image software is highly scriptable and supports complex opperations like masks from color selection etc.

Comment: Since you are already manually marking what you want changed, have you thought about non-technical things like whiteout tape (http://www.amazon.com/Wite-Out-Correction-1-Line-Dispenser-BICWOTAPP11/dp/B003V8Q7HS) or using  non-reflective blank labels or stickers to cover up the mistakes?

Comment: I am a complicated person and this solution is too simple for me;) No, seriously: I am aware of this solution but I have some more ideas in my mind which cannot realized in this way if I want to produce nice handwritten text. E.g. I would like to be able to highlight text in the same way by changing its color. Or to draw a rectangular box around text. These things take a lot of time if I want to do it by hand.

Comment: I don't usually recommend cross-posting, but I bet this would be a good question for http://photo.stackexchange.com? Be sure to include a link to this question there and vice-versa so that everyone knows it's cross posted.

Comment: A solution that I'm thinking is: 1) Segment the object of interest based on the color; 2) Use Flood Fill algorithm to fill the segmented area with the desired color. I don't know Image Magick deeply, but I found that it has `floodfill` algorithm (search "flood" in http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/). It just needs the seed, which would be given by the segmentation. Are you open to OpenCV or Matlab solutions?

Comment: There is a powerful computer vision requirement that you seem to have not considered.  How is the script going to recognize your copy-edits in order to carry them out?

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking in a solution based on ImageMagick. We would need the following steps:

1. Find the color used to draw in the scanned document (for now on, called **target color**);
2. Find its `x` and `y` coordinates in the image;
3. Pass this position as a seed to Flood Fill algorithm.

We could use the following script based on functions of ImageMagick:

1. Output all the unique colors in the picture. This will be used to find out which are the RGB components of the target color ([command source](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=13493)).

   ```
   convert <image> -unique-colors -depth 8 txt:- > output.txt
   ```
2. Output the coordinates of each color in a text file:

   ```
   convert <image> txt:- > coord.txt
   ```
3. Find the `x` and `y` coordinates of the target color ([command source](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20900)). Suppose the target color obtained by step 1 was red:

   ```
   grep red coord.txt
   ```
4. Finally, use `x` and `y` as a seed to `floodfill` to replace the circle region by your desired color ([command source](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=17659)). In this case, I've used `white` to erase the region:

   ```
   convert <image> -fill white -fuzz 13% \
           -draw 'color <x>,<y> floodfill' <image_floodfill_output>
   ```

The `-fuzz` parameter will avoid that colors which were originally `red` and became corrupted due to noise also gets replaced.

This [tutorial](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=17659) gives more information about `floodfill` function, such as how to replace the edge colors.

Comment: +1 for this suggestion. Would be even better if you elaborated it a bit more...   :-)

Comment: @KurtPfeifle thank you! :-) Which points does need improvement? Maybe an example of usage and further explanation about the commands used?

Comment: Exactly :-)  And may even some pictures and text file(extract)s which demonstrate the effects of the commands you're using...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at a scansnap scanner (perhaps the scansnap 3100). There are several things that the bundled software can do that may be helpful.

You may find that any software / script that you find will not work the way you'd like. It sounds like many of these edits are things that need to be seen with a human eye. Perhaps you could hire a personal assistant to make these corrections for you. :)